# how to reset a password in oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

So a long time ago i made an sqldeveloper connection called 'proiect'. I didnt get to work on it for a while so when i got back on it, i got this error

[image]

I tried this right here https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/axdbi/using-sql-plus-to-unlock-accounts-and-reset-passwords.html#GUID-1147D2B9-8FFC-4F91-A774-E97066B4E9C5,the exact same steps with the exact same lines; i altered the user and modified the password, but then when i try again in sqldeveloper, i get the same error.
I dont have any idea, tried a lot of different things but can't figure it out, i tried for like 2 hours now. I know there are some questions asking the same thing but it really doesnt work for me

**EDIT:**
When i changed the password of the user using `alter user identified by password`, i can connect via command line in sql plus and do queries and things, but i can not connect via sql developer. Why is that?

Comment: then you are connecting with the wrong credentials in sql developer if it works from sqlplus

Comment: Either you didn't update the SQL Developer connection properties with the new password, or you did that but incorrectly, or you aren't connecting to the right database - check the hostname, port and service name in SQL Developer match the values you are using in SQL\*Plus, or in your tnsnames.ora if you are using a TNS alias.

Comment: Maybe it is case-sensitive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i read your question, try it like this it might work:
Open command prompt as admin and then connect to system by typing

1.`sqlplus/nolog` and press enter

2.`conn /as sysdba` and press enter again

then you have connected to the system.

now you can edit the password by typing `alter user identified by password`
and after it you will be able to connect to the sql developer.